# Can a bad cell cause excessive heat in charging circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, lipo, overheat

Something I have noticed and am curious of. I had a cases where a lithium ion cell, is bad or dead and it seems to cause overheating in the IC chip on the charging circuit

Today I was having issues with a device that runs a touch display and power supply + battery for my raspberry pi . So I opened up the case to try and do some simple diagnostics. Noticed IC is getting hot.

I know this can happen when a power supply is short of amperage to supply the circuit too, and the port on my device is very loose so maybe it's possible it isn't receiving enough amperage? But is it also possible for a bunk cell to cause excessive heat in a charging circuit?

Comment: *...a lithium ion cell, is bad or dead and it seems to cause overheating in the IC chip on the charging circuit* If the cell is dead then the **battery protection circuit** should have disconnected the battery. Not having battery protection is a sign of a bad design. What looks to you like overheating might be "normal" some ICs are allowed to operate at 90 degrees C which is quite hot by human standards but can be sort of "OK" for a chip in a consumer product.

Comment: *the port on my device is very loose* Then lots of issues can happen, attach the port firmly with a good connection. It is pointless to ask what happens when there is a bad connection present because it depends on the circuit. And it's not how the circuit is supposed to be used.

Comment: Unbalanced cells with balancers get hot to touch but ok if <85’C . you battery unbalance may be aggravating the situation. do some homework and provide test results for Ah, Vbat, temp

Comment: Cells are parallel not series, no balancer. Plus its not the battery that gets hot it's the IC chip on the charging circuit that gets hot. Will replace the broken port tomorrow see if it changes anything.